# JPA: how to select data by child ID in OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, jpql

I have two models Quality and ExpertsData:

```
@Entity(name = "QualityDepartmentData")
@Table(name = "quality")
public class QualityDepartmentData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "qualityId")
    private List<ExpertsData> ListOfExpertsData;
```

```
@Entity(name = "ExpertsData")
@Table(name = "experts")
public class ExpertsData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private Long qualityId;

    private Integer expertId;
```

**I need to fetch list of QualityDepartmentData by the expertId.** Right now I can do it by native MySQL query, like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM quality INNER JOIN experts ON quality.id = experts.quality_id WHERE experts.expert_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<QualityDepartmentData> findAllForExpertId(long id, Pageable pageable);
```

That is working, but the problem is that the native query can't be dynamically sorted, so I need to write query in JPQL for ability to use org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.
Can't find any examples for such event in official JPA docs. Also I tryed many vatiants like this, but it's not working:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT d FROM QualityDepartmentData d INNER JOIN ExpertsData c ON d.id = c.qualityId WHERE c.expertId = ?1")
```

Comment: Here's the documentation on joins in JPQL: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT distinct q FROM QualityDepartmentData q JOIN q.ListOfExpertsData e WHERE e.expertId = ?1")
Page<QualityDepartmentData> findAllForExpertId(Integer id, Pageable pageable);
```

That is working. Thanks for link to example to JB Nizet!